# problem with running rgbdslamV2

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, memory

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My computer configuration: a quad-core CPU with 4GB of memory.

When I run rgbdslamV2,  Memory usage reaches 100%。

How can I do to reduce memory usage? Or I must extend memory？

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221371/problem-with-running-rgbdslamv2/) by [fujisys](https://answers.ros.org/users/25110/fujisys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-11-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2015-11-23**:
I suppose rgdbslam is not very memory efficient. In my experiments I switched from 16 to 32 GB.

**Comment by [fujisys](https://answers.ros.org/users/25110/fujisys/) on 2015-11-25**:
Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hope it's not too late for some tuning advise. If you don't need the point cloud map increase the `cloud_creation_skip_step` to a higher power of two. If you do not have fast motions increase `data_skip_step`.
You could also experiment with the options `create_cloud_every_nth_node` and `store_pointclouds`, but I suspect that they don't work anymore.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0